# Test statistics for null hyposthesis

Tags: probability, statistics

Reginald Brown, an inspector from the Department of Weights and Measures, weighs $15$ 
eighteen-ounce cereal boxes of corn flakes. He finds their mean weight to be $17.78$ 
ounces with a standard deviation of $0.4$ ounces. Are the cereal boxes lighter than they 
should be? Let $a=0.01$.

Here is what I did.

Ho: $u$ is greater than or equal to $18$

Ha: $u$ is less than $18$

df$=15-1=14$

From table the critical value comes out to be $2.624$.

Now how to find test statistics?

Comment: The standard error of the mean is $0.4 / \sqrt{15}$. Does that help?

Comment: it comes out to be 0.10327. how can i do the test statistics now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your H(null) has to be an exact value:
H(null): u = 18; 
Z = (17.78 - 18)/(0.4 / sqrt(15)); 
This will give you a value. If it is smaller than 2.624, then you cannot reject the null hypothesis. If the value is greater than 2.624, you can reject the null hypothesis. It is not a t distribution because it does not say that it follows a normal distribution. So you dont need the degree of freedom. You use Z distribution instead.

Comment: It comes out to be -2.13. It means we will reject it rite?

Comment: No because you are performing a left tail test. If you calculated Z(alpha) correctly for 0.01, you should make it negative. Thus, we cannot reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: You can reject it if the value is less than -2.624

Comment: okay thanks alot sir :)